# Docker container with Spring and Postgres error. org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "meetings" does not exist

Tags: java, spring, docker, docker-compose

While launching my Docker container using 'docker-compose up' command I get this type of error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "meetings" does not exist
```

My application.properties file is this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgresqldb:5432/meetingsdb?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&stringtype=unspecified
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=db
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

My Dockerfile is this:

```
FROM openjdk:11
ADD target/visma-meeting-app-withdb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

And my docker-compose.yaml file is this:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
app:
container_name: docker-meetings
image: docker_meetings
build: ./
ports:
- "8080:8080"
expose:
- "8080"
depends_on:
- postgresqldb
environment:
- SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgresqldb:5432/meetingsdb?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&stringtype=unspecified
- SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
- SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=db
- SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=none
postgresqldb:
image: postgres
ports:
- "5432:5432"
expose:
- "5432"
environment:
- POSTGRES_USER=postgres
- POSTGRES_PASSWORD=db
- POSTGRES_DB=meetingsdb
```

When I try to run my application not in Docker everything seems to work fine, but when I do this using Docker I get an error. Can someone help? Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: Your database is empty, so your program can't find the tables it expects

Comment: How come my database is empty. If I run it like regular Spring application it connects and picks the results from database and all is fine. But in Docker there is this problem.